# Cobol exponential with very high numbers: finding 5 ** 365 etc

Tags: cobol, exponential, truncation

** is used to compute exponentiation values in Cobol. That works OK with "small" numbers for example 5 ** 10 and so on.

Now there is a task where we should find X ** 365 + X ** 364 + X ** 363 + X ** 362 + X ** 361 + ... etc. where X is a decimal number with V9(02).

If ** is used with higher numbers for example 5.00 ** 41 then Truncation of high order digit positions occurs due to the fact that I'm able to keep PIC S9(29)V9(02) COMP-3 MAX (31 digits) with CBL ARITH(EXTEND) option.

Is there a work-around for this / Exponential function?

Is it possible at all on Cobol Enterprise for z/Os?

Comment: It would be natural to do this with "floating point". There are documented limits to the number of powers of 10 there. What are you trying to do? Why are you trying to stuff the result into 9(29)V99?

Comment: Comp-1 / comp-2 are Cobols floating point options on Z-OS. Note you do not specify a picture when you use them. From memory  `03 field-name  Comp-1`

Comment: With no response, and the intended exponentiation way outside limits for Enterprise COBOL, attempting to close.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

The array "big-one" is like having a 1000 byte long numeric field.
i.e. pic 9(1000)

For "5 ** 365", you set mult to 5 and thymes to 365.

Since normal cobol won't support arithmetic on such large numbers, you have to do it yourself.

Start by setting big9(1000) to 1.
This is like having pic 9(1000) value 1.

Then loop "thymes" times thru paragraph "do-mult" that multiplies the digits of big-one by "mult', handling any "karry", by adding it to the intermediate result when calculating on the previous digit.

At the end, the digits of big-one represent the result.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.

   PROGRAM-ID.  cb043.

   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.

   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.

   FILE-CONTROL.

   DATA DIVISION.

   FILE SECTION.

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

   01  sub1 pic 9(05).

   01  big-one.

       03  big9 occurs 1000 pic 9(01).

   01  mult pic 9(06) value 5.

   01  thymes pic 9(03) value 365.

   01  sub2 pic 9(05).

   01  sub3 pic 9(05).

   01  interm pic 9(10).

   01  filler redefines interm.

       03  karry pic 9(09).

       03  rite pic 9.

   01  staw pic 9(09).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.

   MAINLINE.
```

******* zeroise the big array

```
       perform varying sub1

          from 1 by 1

        until sub1 > 1000

           move 0 to big9(sub1)

       end-perform.
```

******* make big-one like pic 9(1000) value 1

```
       MOVE 1 to big9(1000).
```

******* do the multiplication "thymes" times

```
       perform varying sub2

          from 1 by 1

         until sub2 > thymes

           perform do-mult

       end-perform.
```

******* find the first non-zero digit

```
       perform varying sub1

          from 1 by 1

         until big9(sub1) not = 0

       end-perform.
```

******* display the digits of the result

```
       perform varying sub2

          from sub1 by 1

         until sub2 > 1000

           display sub2 big9(sub2)

       end-perform.

       stop run.

   do-mult.
```

******* zeroise the stored carry field, "staw"

```
       move 0 to staw.
```

******* multiply every digit of "big-one"

******* starting at big9(1000) and working backwards to big9(1)

******* the left hand 9 bytes of "interm", represent any carry, as "karry"

******* which is stored in "staw" and is added when the next calculation is

******* done

---

```
       perform varying sub3

          from 1000 by -1

         until sub3 = 0

           compute interm = (big9(sub3) * mult)

                          + staw

           move karry to staw

           move rite to big9(sub3)

       end-perform.
```

Answer (score 0):

Some problems:

First, `5 ** 365` requires 255 digits.

Second pic `S9(29)V9(02)` requires that `x` be somewhat less than `1.2`.

However, `x` is defined as `V9(02)` (unless something more was intended). The "work-around" is logarithms. FUNCTION LOG10 is available in Enterprise COBOL.

```
identification division.
program-id. big-exp.
data division.
1 x binary pic v99 value 0.99.
1 log10-of-x comp-2.
1 value-of-x-to-n comp-2.
1 sum-of-values comp-2 value 0.
1 disp-sum pic z(3).9(15).
1 n binary pic 9(3).
procedure division.
begin.
   compute log10-of-x = function log10 (x)
   perform varying n from 365 by -1
   until n = 0
       compute value-of-x-to-n = 10 ** (log10-of-x * n)
       compute sum-of-values = sum-of-values +
           value-of-x-to-n
   end-perform
   move sum-of-values to disp-sum
   display disp-sum
   stop run
   .
```

For `x = 0.99` the answer is approximately `96.473721519223000`.

But note that as x drops below approximately `0.10`, underflow may occur.